# Bootstrap Center col-sm divs inside row class

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I have a row that contains a dynamic number of col-sm-3 divs. I was hoping to have it so inside the row the col-sm-3 divs would be centered, instead of left aligned

here is some sample code:

```
<div class="custom-fields row custom-field-output">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
             content 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
             content 2
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I'd like to have the two col-sm-3 divs horizontally centered inside the row div.

Comment: I've been messing w/ this for the past few hours but for some reason I cannot get my version to center! doh! so weird.. I will keep you updated as i find more

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<div class="custom-fields row custom-field-output">
    <div class="row col col-sm-12">
        <div class="col col-sm-3 col-offset-3">
             content 1
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-3 ">
             content 2
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following, and check this source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

```
<div class="custom-fields row custom-field-output">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="custom-fields row custom-field-output">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**this code will use to keep left-right margin same..**

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<div class="custom-fields row custom-field-output">
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 content 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 content 2
            </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late on this one, but I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
<div class="custom-fields row custom-field-output">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
             content 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
             content 2
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```